# Hibernate and SQL Server dependency

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am trying to use Hibernate and SQL Server 2008. I have come across installation of sqljdbc4 into my local Maven Repository. It gives me an error and I have not been able to move forward.

I'm not sure how my local repository should look like (newbie), but the mvn command is giving the error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:m
aven-install-plugin:jar:2.4: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
 resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:mav
en-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpa
th.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifac
t descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:269)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:239)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:233)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:108)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/m
aven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not trans
fer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path buil
ding failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven
2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer
artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
 failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: This error comes when you are trying to install sqljdbc4 in your local repo?

Comment: Can you provide your pom.xml showing sqljdbc4  dependency

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer a while back but just thought it is fair to post it here.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server/db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">here</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">here</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">100</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you triend install command like this?

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0
```

Typical maven output on the command

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Installing c:\Data\****\****\temp\sqljdbc4.jar to C:\Users\****\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\sqljdbc4\4.0\sqljdbc4-4.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.458 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-01T15:40:03+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/241M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Maven dependency should look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Another alternative to installing sqljdbc4 to local maven repository is to reference it from local filesystem, but there are limitations - path is relative to particular maven module. In one of projects, i put sqljdbc in `references` directory that is at the same level as maven modules directory and added it as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../references/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @Viktor, I have been trying that. I am not sure where the problem is. The mvn command tries to download and then it shows the error above.

Comment: Just tried exactly the command i've suggested on Maven 3.2.3 in Windows environment. I've edited my answer and added output Maven produced. I have no idea why it dosen't work for you, maybe different version or mispelled command.